# How to remove a class from my calendar if 20 are booked onto it

Tags: javascript, php

I want to remove the class from the calendar if 20 book that class. I have an admin side to the system where I add classes into the database but I need to do a check to see if more than 20 people are booked onto the class then the class will disappear from the calendar. I have no idea how to go about starting this, this is my code I have to insert a class to the calendar. I think I have to add a check in this code.

```
if(isset($_POST["title"]))
{
 $query = "
 INSERT INTO events 
 (title, start_event, end_event) 
 VALUES (:title, :start_event, :end_event)
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute(
  array(
   ':title'  => $_POST['title'],
   ':start_event' => $_POST['start'],
   ':end_event' => $_POST['end']
  )
 );
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you.  How would we know what your fields are?  How do we know what the data association looks like for people booking the class?

Comment: Overall your question is too broad but in general, I assume each booking is it's own record in the database with a foreign key to a class or similar. I assume when retrieving the classes from the database for the calendar the number of bookings can be included in the records. That will allow you to inspect the number at the time you bind it to the calendar and then either hide the class on the calendar or mark it as full or what ever else you want, etc...

Comment: The proper point in time to do the "class is full" check is after somebody has booked it. If they happened to be the 20th person, remove the class.

Comment: You need also add backend verification as well as 2 or more people could be looking at a class in the calendar with 19 bookings and not refresh the page and kick off a booking. Hence it is also needed to include the state of a class with each retrieval from the database or exclude classes which ever way is fine, depending how it fits into the domain design of OP. Without OP having anything implemented yet, all solutions are subjective I'd assume.

Comment: So where is the query that selects the lists of classes?

Answer (score -1):

You should do that verification within the database by creating a function or using a trigger. If you use a function, return the number of records or true/false based on the number of records.

Or simply query the database after inserting to see if the number of records has reached 20:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events;
```

Then use your php logic to remove the class.